# Concept of JSF, EJB and form based login with JDBC-Realm

Tags: jsf, netbeans, ejb

I am trying to learn the concepts of Java EE (EJB,JSF...) and therefore I am working on an example application.
Unfortunately I have problems to understand how some concepts should work together and if I am doing it in an correct professional manner. At this point, I am really confused about all these different methods and hope someone can help me out.

The core functionality of my application consists of a document server where registered users can upload documents and describe it with useful information.

The Documents should simply be saved on the Server and all Information should be stored in a MySQL Database.
I created three Projects with Netbeans.

- Enterprise Application Project (DocApp)
- EJB Module (DocApp-ejb)
- and a Web Application Project (DocApp-war).

The main things work fine like

- accessing the database with JPA
- uploading files with primefaces FileUploader
- injecting JSF with EJB
- and even the **user authorization** with **JDBC-Realm** as shown in this tutorial
  http://jugojava.blogspot.de/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html

My Problem now is, that all pages in a specific subdirectory should only be accessible by **registered users**.

The only way i see is to use one **SessionScoped**  **ManagedBean**, instead of using multiple **RequestScoped**  **ManagedBeans** .
This seems to be a bad practice but I have no Idea how to handle this otherwise.
The way i understand it, there should be one ManagedBeand for every JSF Page (xhtml).

Is there a good way to handle this or am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The default mechanism to give access to a whole sub directory is adding a security constraint in web.xml for the URL pattern representing that directory.

Every registered user should get a role that represents being registered, eg "REGISTERED"

This role is then added to the security constraint in web.xml.

The interaction between JSF and the Servlet container managed security is a little awkward, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this is how it should work. But if I do it this way, then every time there is  an redirect to another page in that directory, the login information is gone unless I create **ONE** SessionScoped ManagedBean, which is bad practise I guess.

Comment: I see.What is exactly "login information" in your book? Is that your own object in eg session scope, or the fact whether HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole doesn't return true?

Comment: I am not familiar with the function HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole.  With "login information" i meant username/password. I am using a form based login and security constraints. If the session is over, I am getting redirected to the login page.

Comment: It's hard for me to judge if you really did a container login or not. If you're not using isUserInRole or @RolesAllowed, you may not. What does HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal return at the point you think you are logged-in?

Comment: Hi Mike, there was a problem with the timeout configuration in the Session Properties. I changed the value from 10 to 1000. But right there I have a problem of understanding. What exactly is a Session, where does is starts and end? Is a Authorization session independent from the ManagedBean Scope variant? Does it care if it is Session or Request Scoped?  With getUserPrincipal.getName() I get the same as with getRemoteUser(), the current Username.

Comment: @SuiTheDoc That are a lot of basic questions for which the comment section is not really suited, but a session in this context is an http session. A server creates it for you at the first page request. You get a JSESSIONID cookie. Send the cookie back with following requests and those request can access data for that session instance. It ends when it times out, or you explicitly destroy it. Session scoped managed beans are all part of a specific session, identified by the key in that cookie.